# How to use Azure AD B2B with Authorization code with PKCE flow in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use Azure AD B2B for authorization code with PKCE flow in my ReactJS app. I have searched in google all examples are with angular and with azure b2c. Couldn't find a working sample with ReactJS with azure b2b. Can anyone guide me how to use PKCE flow with Azure B2B and ReactJS app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at samples using MSAL for React.js, e.g. [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/react). The only special wrt to allowing B2B users is to make sure you do not use the /common endpoint when redirecting to AAD but. identify the specific tenant you want to use, e.g. login.microsoftonline.com/**contoso.com**. Other than that AAD does not care whether you are authenticating a local or B2B user.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for reply. I have followed the link, but it using implicit flow. I want to use authorization code PKCE flow. So can you please guide me how to use azure b2b for PKCE flow and corresponding JS library to use it.

Comment: AAD does not support PKCE with JS browser code (it does for native code only). I understand supporting JS would open some DDOS script-based attack surfaces so for now its blocked.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 is recommending PKCE flow for browser based apps also. If PKCE is not supported by AAD for browser based app, then I have to switch to some other security service provider. Thanks for the information.